# jQuery to display 7 days after the current date

Tags: jquery

I have got a task to display seven days from the current date with ability to select only one of them. My  code is:

```
function setCurrentDate(_id) {
    var _dat = document.querySelector(_id);
    var hoy = new Date(),
              d = hoy.getDate(),
              m = hoy.getMonth()+1, 
              y = hoy.getFullYear(),
              data;

    if(d < 10) {
        d = "0"+d;
    };

    if(m < 10) {
        m = "0"+m;
    };

    data = y+"-"+m+"-"+d;
    _dat.value = data;
};

function setMaxDate(_id) {
    var _dat = document.querySelector(_id);
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var diff = 7; // days
    var futureTime = now + 7*24*60*60*1000;
    var future = new Date(futureTime);
    _dat.value = future;
};

setCurrentDate("#from");
setMaxDate("#to");
```

But I need to get them in the following view:

> Today | Tomorrow | 03-02-2016 | 04-02-2016 | 05-02-2016 | 06-02-2016 | 07-02-2016

Please help me with amending my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vmr2449r/

Update: **I have managed to create the code in a little bit different way but if there is a chance to optimise my jQuery? See it here**: http://jsfiddle.net/5sjnbq21/

Comment: Well, your max date is correct: it's 7 days from now.  Today is the first, add 7, that's the 8th of Feb.  In order to display as you'd like you need to calculate *five* consecutive values, each offset by 1 day, the first being 2 days in the future ("Tomorrow" would be +1 day).

Comment: Do you mean in text box?

Comment: I mean no text boxes just view like this: Today | Tomorrow | 03-02-2016 | 04-02-2016 | 05-02-2016 | 06-02-2016 | 07-02-2016

Comment: Hi @Draco18s can you show on jsfiddle how to do a couple of them please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easier way to display the next 7 days.
Let me know if you need help understanding the code or changing it.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + i);
  $("body").append("<div id='day" + i + "'>" + ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + date.getFullYear() + "</div>");
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sjnbq21/1/)